# How to obtain idempotent solution in this question. Let $\bf{B}=\Omega^{-1/2}X(X^T\Omega^{-1}X)^{-1}X^T\Omega^{-1/2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\mathbf B=\mathbf \Omega^{-1/2}\mathbf X\left(\mathbf X^T\mathbf \Omega^{-1}\mathbf X\right)^{-1}\mathbf X^T\mathbf \Omega^{-1/2}$, where $\,{\bf X}_{N\times K},{\bf \Omega}^{-1/2}_{N\times N}\,$ and $\mathbf \Omega^{-1/2}\times \mathbf \Omega^{-1/2}=\mathbf \Omega^{-1}$.

$\bullet$ Find $\mathbf B \mathbf \Omega^{-1/2}\mathbf X$

$\bullet$ Find $(\mathbf I-\mathbf B)^2$

For the first question I simply do it as

\begin{align*}
\mathbf B \mathbf \Omega^{-1/2}\mathbf X&=\mathbf \Omega^{-1/2}\mathbf X\left(\mathbf X^T\mathbf \Omega^{-1}\mathbf X\right)^{-1}\mathbf X^T\mathbf \Omega^{-1/2}\times \mathbf \Omega^{-1/2}\mathbf X\\
&=\mathbf \Omega^{-1/2}\mathbf X\left(\mathbf X^T\mathbf \Omega^{-1}\mathbf X\right)^{-1}\mathbf X^T\mathbf \Omega^{-1}\mathbf X\\
&=\mathbf \Omega^{-1/2}\mathbf X\left(\mathbf X^T\mathbf \Omega^{-1}\mathbf X\right)^{-1}\left(\mathbf X^T\mathbf \Omega^{-1}\mathbf X\right)\\
&=\mathbf \Omega^{-1/2}\mathbf X
\end{align*}

From here we could infer $\mathbf B=\mathbf I$, sequentially the next question's solution will be a zero matrix. However, the tutor said $ (\mathbf I-\mathbf B)^2$ is not zero matrix, he said a word cannot remember exactly, probably idempotent. I don't see why.

Thanks for any comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(I-B)^2 = B^2 -2B + I$$
notice
$$B^2 = B\Omega^{-1/2}X(X^T\Omega^{-1}X)^{-1}X^T\Omega^{-1/2} = (B\Omega^{-1/2}X)(X^T\Omega^{-1}X)^{-1}X^T\Omega^{-1/2}$$
$$\stackrel{(1)}{=} \Omega^{-1/2}X(X^T\Omega^{-1}X)^{-1}X^T\Omega^{-1/2}=B$$
where (1) comes from your earlier calculation. Overal this gives
$$(I-B)^2 = I-B$$
a square matrix $A$ such that $A^2=A$ is called idempotent.

To adress why $B\neq I$, notice
$$\bf{B}\Omega^{-1/2}X=\Omega^{-1/2}X \Longleftrightarrow 0 = (I-B)\Omega^{-1/2}X$$
In general
$$MN = 0 \not\Longrightarrow M =0 \text{ or } N=0$$
Counter-example
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
0&0\\
3&4
\end{pmatrix} = 0$$